# how to get multiple select value using ajax select

Tags: php, ajax, select

I'm new to this scripting ... still in the process of learning. I have a puzzle to myself and i need help. Help are appreciated. Below is the situation:

I have two select option with different number value. upon select first and second without refresh the two value will be added. How can i Obtained a script using ajax without refreshing the page.

```
<select name="select1"><option value="123"></option></select>
<select name="select2"><option value="546"></option></select>

<div id="addition">here the two value will be added...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This Might help you.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addemall()
{
var num1,num2,tot=0;
num1=document.getElementById("num1");
num2=document.getElementById("num2");
if(num1.value&&num2.value){
tot=parseInt(num1.value)+parseInt(num2.value);
}
document.getElementById("addition").innerHTML="Total :- "+tot+"";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="select1" id="num1" onChange="addemall();">
<option value="1001">1001</option>
<option value="123">123</option>
</select>
<select name="select2" id="num2" onChange="addemall();">
<option value="1001">1001</option>
<option value="546">546</option>
</select>
<div id="addition">here the two value will be added...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is Javascript Program. But you should really have a look at Document Object Model(DOM).

I don't think that you need ajax here.

Hope it'll help. Previous Code wasn't working because the function was named `add()` and i don't know why it is giving the problem. But I've changed my answer now and it works. please do have a look at that.

Comment: It works vedants thanks ... one more questions. Can I display the value in <input value> instead of div?

Comment: I'm exploring by reading other post ... from this code "document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;" how can you display it in 'input text' instead of div?

Comment: I found answer instead of .innerHTML replace it to .value  thanks to all it really help me a lot ...

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
<script>
var val1 = ~~($('select[name="select1"]').val()); //~~(x) is the same as floor(x)
var val2 = ~~($('select[name="select2"]').val());
var val = val1 + val2;
$('#addition').html(val);
</script>
```

and no ajax is needed. However, if for some reason you want to sum the two numbers server-side you can send them over with ajax like that:

```
<script>
var val1 = ~~($('select[name="select1"]').val()); //~~(x) is the same as floor(x)
var val2 = ~~($('select[name="select2"]').val());
$.ajax
({
   type:"POST",
   async:true,
   url:"addition.php",
   data:{val1:val1, val2:val2}
}).done(function(msg)
{
   $('#addition').html(msg);
});
</script>
```

and have the file addition.php read the two POST values and add them together.